# Passing props with forEach in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, react-props

I'm following the FullstackOpen 2023 course (https://fullstackopen.com/en/) and in part2 there is an assignment that asks you to render a collection with the following App.jsx:

```
import Course from './components/Course'

const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'
  const parts = [
    {
      name: 'Fundamentals of React',
      exercises: 10
    },
    {
      name: 'Using props to pass data',
      exercises: 7
    },
    {
      name: 'State of a component',
      exercises: 14
    }
  ] 

  return (    
    <div>
      <Course header={course} content={parts} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass to the Couse component the object parts, and trying to render its properties with a forEach. This is the Course.jsx file:

```
const Part = ({ part }) => {

    <p>
        {part.name} {part.exercises}
    </p>

}

const Course = ({ header, content }) => {

    <h1>{header}</h1>

    content.forEach(x => {        
        <Part part={x}
         />
    })
}

export default Course
```

However, the browser displays nothing.

I've tried to use map() and still shows nothing. I've also tried to debug with

```
content.forEach(x => {        
        console.log(x);

        <Part part={x}/>
    })
```

and in the console it shows it perfecly:
[image]

**Why is this not working?**

---

EDIT:

Wow OK, lessons learned:

1. Every component must have a Return statement
2. 

What comes after the arrow function symbol (=>) is key:

When using the following:

```
=> { }
```

React understand that there is a body with NO implicit return, so you have to use it:

```
=> { return ( ) }
```

However, using

```
=> ()
```

means that React understands that, what comes inside the `( )` is a return.

3. map needs a return statment, thus using

```
map (x => {} )
```

is NOT equivalent to using

```
map (x => () )
```

Sorry for the n00b question, i've just started learning React and destructuring, while handy, is (still) confusing.

Comment: Just at a glance... (1) The `Part` and `Course` components don't *return* anything, you're missing the `return` keyword.  (2) Use `.map()` in the JSX structure, not `.forEach()`.  The latter doesn't return anything.  (3) In the `Course` component you'll need to wrap the two adjacent JSX structures in an enclosing structure.  Which could be a React fragment, a `<div>`, whatever you like.

Comment: In `content.forEach(x => { <Part part={x} /> })`, you're creating an element and then just throwing it away. Nothing ever uses the element you created. Instead, use `map` and return the element (and return or otherwise use the result of calling `map`), more in [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists). Be sure to provide a valid [key](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists) ([**not**](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) just the index).